# registerAutoloaders must be compatible with Phalcon\Mvc\ModuleDefinitionInterface

Tags: phalcon

I very need multiple structure application. I used phalcon v3, now migrating v4.

```
I get error: Fatal error: Declaration of Multiple\Frontend\Module::registerAutoloaders(?Phalcon\DiInterface $di = NULL) 
must be compatible with 
Phalcon\Mvc\ModuleDefinitionInterface::registerAutoloaders
(?Phalcon\Di\DiInterface $container = NULL) in frontend/Module.php on line 13
```

I cloned https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple and get same error. Please, help :(

Comment: Its decision: use Phalcon\Di\DiInterface;

Comment: you may want to check the documentation https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/upgrade

Answer (score 2):

change
Phalcon\DiInterface;
for
Phalcon\Di\DiInterface;

Comment: v3 to v4 =>  "Phalcon\DiInterface"  to  "Phalcon\Di\DiInterface"  :)